# Web Service authorization issue

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

Need some help with KDSoap 1.7 or gSOAP

I'm trying to use some Web Service API: http://sparkgatetest.interfax.ru/iFaxWebService/ . There is list of methods and to interact with them u must:

1. call Authmethod
2. call any method u need to
3. call End

Problem is, this is HTTP protocol, so if you used Authmothod succesfully, and after that trying to call methods which return some information, u got an "Authorization error" message in xml response.

So, to correct usage of this API u should call three methods (Authmethod, some method, End) in one request. How should I do it with KDSoap/gSOAP?

p.s. i found setAuthentication function in client interface, but it takes KDSoapAuthentication class as argument, maybe there is a way to customize it? And End method also a big problem aswell.